# Search Hash Map array for specfic key android

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` of `HashMap` like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> playListSongs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I populate the list like this:

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < nl.getLength(); i1++) {
  // creating new HashMap
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  Element e = (Element) nl.item(i1);
  // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
  map.put(KEY_SONGS, String.valueOf(i1));
  map.put(KEY_FILE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FILE));
  map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
  map.put(KEY_FILE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FILE));
  map.put(KEY_ALBUM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ALBUM));
  map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
  map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
  map.put(KEY_ARTWORK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTWORK));
  // Songs List of selected playlist
  playListSongs.add(map);
  // list view bind
  PopulateList(playListSongs);
}
```

Now i want to Get Album and songs of a specific Artist and song count from HashMap-array-list(playListSongs) to bind it to the list view.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am new to android and I am curious to an answer because from what I know, using adapters with a list view only works numerically. You might consider using numerical values instead. I could be wrong of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method to get songs of specific artist:

```
private ArrayList<String> getSongsByArtist(String artist){
    ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : playListSongs) {
        if(hashMap.get(KEY_ARTIST).equals(artist)){
            songs.add(hashMap.get(KEY_TITLE));
        }
    }
    return songs;       
}
```

To get distinct artists use following method:

```
private ArrayList<String> getDistinctArtists(){
    HashMap<String,String> duplicateTracker = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<String> distinctArtists = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : playListSongs) {
        // Check whether artist is already added or not
        if(duplicateTracker.containsKey(hashMap.get(KEY_ARTIST))==false){
            //Add artist name to hash map
            duplicateTracker.put(hashMap.get(KEY_ARTIST), hashMap.get(KEY_ARTIST));
            distinctArtists.add(hashMap.get(KEY_ARTIST));
        }
    }
    return distinctArtists;     
}
```

Comment: kool , my Question is how do i get only Distinct Artist From Array list , as one artist have many songs in array list

Comment: I have added the method to get distinct artists from array list

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
     for (int i1 = 0; i1 < playListSongs.size(); i1++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = playListSongs.get(i1);
String artist=map.get(KEY_ARTIST);                    
String songs=   map.get(KEY_SONGS);
String file=   map.get(KEY_FILE);
String duration=   map.get(KEY_DURATION);

SongDescription description=new SongDescription(artists,songs,file,duration);
desList.add(description);                     
if(artists.equals(desiredAtrist)){
songs----------->You need
}
```

}

Comment: very simple,as you made a list(n1) before putting in map,just do the reverse

Comment: see the updated answer.You already made playListSong list.just like that

Comment: Playlist is a Raw List its like                                                   ARTIST      Album                                                            enrique     Insomanic                                                   otherArtist  OtherAlbum

Comment: You know desired artist.right?So just compare and if it is then put in the list